Why can’t OneDrive show shortcut icon on the sidebar in macOS?
I have two OneDrive accounts on my MacBook, and one of them stopped showing up on the sidebar. I tried some suggestions online to make sure the box of the cloud drives in the location session of the sidebar favourite is checked, but it still didn't work.
Any ideas?

Actually I found a solution:

Find OneDrive in your Applications folder.
Right-click OneDrive and select Show Package Contents.
Browse to the Contents > Resources folder.
Double-click ResetOneDriveAppStandalone.command or ResetOneDriveApp.command
Start OneDrive and log in to your accounts
Since it's started, OneDrive archived your previous files in a different folder just in case, located at ~/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-DriveName(Date). Please compare the files to make sure no recent changes are lost

